# Robust way to deploy a Rack application (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, deployment, nginx, sinatra, rack

I'm looking for a **robust way to deploy a Rack application** (in this case a Sinatra app).  Requests will take a little time (0.25-0.5 sec waiting on proxied HTTP requests) and there may be a decent amount of traffic.

Should I go with a traditional mongrel cluster setup?  Use HAProxy as a load balancer?  nginx?  rackup?

What solutions have you used and what are the advantages?

Comment: Are you getting paid for sysadmin on this, or are you looking for a 'fire and forget' setup?

Comment: sorry @stef, but your question in the comment keep me wandering. What change if I get paid as sysdamin or if I need a fire and forget set up? what will we be best option in both cases?

Thanks

Comment: using Heroku is probably the easiest (git push heroku), but if you end up needing to have other applications, libraries and so on in your stack that's not an option so you would need to look at a self-hosted setup which adds a sysadmin responsibility.

Comment: I haven't found any libraries Heroku can't support yet; their Cedar stack is quite flexible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nginx / Unicorn FTW!

Nginx in front to serve static files and unicorn to handle Sinatra app.

Benefits: Performance, good load balancing with unix socks and deploy/upgrade without any downtimes (you can upgrade Ruby/Nginx/Sinatra/app without downtime).

How-to : http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/ .

Answer (score 4):

Nginx / passenger.

Nginx is very light, performant and has readable configuration files. Passenger is solid, easy to set up and works very well with rack - just have your config.ru in your app's main dir. Passenger can also take care of spawning processes and load balancing for you.