# Continuously run Sinatra on Apache server

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is it possible to `ssh` into a server, start a `Ruby` program with `Sinatra`, and then log out of the `ssh` session, and still have the `Sinatra` server run? I have tried this, but it seems that when I log out of the server, the `Sinatra` server quits. Am I doing something wrong? If I can't do this, how would I run `Sinatra` continuously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually due to the shell (for example bash) exiting and sending hangup or kill signals to all its child processes. To start the server in the background and shield it from the HUP signal you can use the command [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

```
    nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
```

For example:

```
nohup ruby sinatra_app.rb &
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

For more robust deployment options you might want to look at something like [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)   and/or [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/):

[Robust way to deploy a Rack application (Sinatra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486320/robust-way-to-deploy-a-rack-application-sinatra)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I kill the process if I needed to?

Comment: ps -ef | grep ruby; kill -9 ppid of process from the grep

Comment: Also, you should really consider the more robust deployment options

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [gnu screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

But nohup is probably the "smallest thing that can possibly work". Screen can help out if you start multiple things and want to handle them differently.